# remove row if there are zeros in 2 specific columns (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   1   0     6    7
row2   5   7     0    6
row3   0   0     4    6
```

And I need to remove rows only if they contain zeros in the column 1 and 2. So far I've managed to remove all columns with zeros:

```
mk<-mk[apply(mk!=0, 1, all),]
```

but don't know how to restrict to only rows which have zeros in columns 1 and 2 specifically.

Expected result:

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   1   0     6    7
row2   5   7     0    6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use  `rowSums` to create a logical vector. i.e. subset the first two columns of 'mk', check if it is equal to 0, get the `rowSums` of logical matrix and convert to a logical vector with `<` 2, use that as row index to subset the rows

```
mk[rowSums(mk[, 1:2] == 0) < 2,]
#     col1 col2 col3 col4
#row1    1    0    6    7
#row2    5    7    0    6
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
mk[!apply(mk[, 1:2]==0, 1, all),]
#     col1 col2 col3 col4
#row1    1    0    6    7
#row2    5    7    0    6
```

Or with `any`

```
mk[apply(mk[, 1:2], 1, any),]
```

#### data

```
mk <- structure(c(1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 6L), 
.Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(
    c("row1", "row2", "row3"),
    c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"
    )))
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! Can you explain what the < 2 means, tho? and how can I change the command to apply the same principle to columns 1 and 3, for example?

Comment: @Manuel here, we are using 2 columns is 1 and 2, and we want to have rows where the number of 0s is less than 2 ie. not all elements are 0

Comment: @Manuel for that just change the index `mk[, c(1, 3)]` instead of `mk[, 1:2]` the `:` is sequence because if you want to have columns from 1 to 5 `1:5`, for selected ones `c(1, 3, 5)`